# How does the metric change under scale transformations?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems

I was reading Zee's book in Group Theory, chapter VIII.2 (The Conformal Algebra) and I'm stuck in something probably easy:

In p.516, he states that under a scale transformation, $x'^{\mu} = \lambda x^{\mu}$, the metric changes as:

$g'_{\rho\sigma}(x') = g'_{\rho\sigma}(\lambda x) = \lambda^2g_{\mu\nu}(x)$

However, this result seems wrong to me. First, the indices are wrong and using the general formula for transforming the metric I get:

$g'_{\rho\sigma}(x') = g_{\mu\nu}(x)\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x'^{\rho}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x'^{\sigma}} = \frac{g_{\mu\nu}(x)}{\lambda^2}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\rho}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\sigma}} = \frac{g_{\mu\nu}(x)}{\lambda^2} \delta^{\mu}_{\rho}\delta^{\nu}_{\sigma} = \frac{g_{\rho\sigma}(x)}{\lambda^2}$

Is something wrong in my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think he means something more mundane i.e $g_{\mu \nu} dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu} \rightarrow g_{\mu \nu} d (\lambda x^{\mu})d( \lambda x^{\nu}) = g_{\mu \nu} \lambda^2 dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu} $. Then we can define new components $g_{\mu \nu}' =g_{\mu \nu} \lambda^2 $. I think the confusion comes from the fact that we are not actually talking about a coordinate transformation (at least not in the usual sense). Consider the following: I have basis set $\{e_i\}$ and $\{e_j\}$. We can write a vector in each as follows $v=v^ie_i$ or $v=v^je_j$. There is a linear transformation $A_{ij}e_j = e_i$. This means $v = v^iA_{ij}e_j$ and therefore switching from the $\{e_i\}$ basis to $\{e_j\}$ requires multiplication of $v$ by $A^T$ or orthogonal transformations specifically $A^{-1}$.Something like this is what you have in mind with the equations you wrote.

I think what Zee has in mind is the following. In a specific coordinate system $\{e_a\}$, we can write the components of the covariant tensor as $g_{ab}=e_a \cdot e_b$. But *in this coordinate system* perform a scaling transformation. What do the matrix elements of the matrix tensor look like? Well, $e_a \rightarrow \lambda e_a$ so $g_{ab}' = \lambda e_a \cdot \lambda e_b = \lambda^2 e_a \cdot e_b = \lambda^2 g_{ab}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think it is clearer now, but I still believe Zee's explanation was quite confusing!

Comment: I have his book on quantum field theory and I have a love hate relationship with it because of things like this. You want simplification of conceptual point, Zee is the way to go. If you want clarifying calculations, then I am not so sure.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem today with conformal transformations and your answer was pure gold. I think it is ok to say that at these transformations you can either change the basis (passive point of view) OR the components (active) of a tensor, while at what we call coordinate transformations you change both the basis AND the components (such that the tensor is the same, just from two equivalent points of view)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your logic.
I believe that you have found a typographical error in Zee's book.
Congratulations!